# XAML Line Stroke of PhoneAccentColor causes unhandled exception

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Map map control (the older Bing map from Windows 7 as the new one isn't as versatile for me needs).

I programmatically add a Canvas control with a Line in it to the map. All works fine when

```
<Line ... Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
```

but if I change the stroke to PhoneAccentColor an unhandled exception occurs

```
<Line ... Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}" />
```

Here's the stack trace from unhandled exception:

```
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.MapLayer.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
```

Any ideas what the issue might be?

In case it's relevant, my code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
            <Canvas Height="300" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Line X1="150" X2="150" Y1="0" Y2="130" Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}" Margin="0"/>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and the C# using it:

```
ContentControl content = new ContentControl();
content.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["MyTemplate"];
Viewbox viewbox = new Viewbox();
viewbox.Width = 300;
viewbox.Height = 300;
viewbox.Child = content;
Map.Children.Add(viewbox);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **PhoneAccentBrush** instead of PhoneAccentColor. Because PhoneAccentColor is typeof Color. But Stroke need type is Brush.

```
<Line ... Stroke="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />
```

or defind Stroke as a SolidColorBrush and use PhoneAccentColor to set Color:

```
<Line>
    <Line.Stroke>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}"/>
    </Line.Stroke>
</Line>
```